# Does SPARQL literals have a type?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to write a sparql query to extract all predicates from DBPedia that their subjects are `Person` and their objects are Date Literals. 
This is my query:

```
SELECT ?o ?p ?d
from <http://dbpedia.org>
where{
?o <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>.
?d <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/property/date>. 
?o ?p ?d.
}
```

The query doesn't show any result and it seems that I have to define date literals in another way. I wonder to know what is the right way to define the type of literals.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem.

Comment: You can learn much from the [SPARQL 1.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/)...

Comment: @StanislavKralin could you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @JeenBroekstra, I've deleted my commen; your answer will be definitely better!